# Encoding 8bit characters in email body to hash before DKIM signatures c#

Tags: c#, email, dkim

I have written an email server which basically receives an email and forwards it on as is. I am now adding DKIM signatures to the headers. This works fine for 7bit encoded email bodies (or quoted-printable / base64).

The problem I'm having is for 8bit encoded bodies containing 8bit characters. I could encode the whole body as quoted-printable and forward it as quoted-printable (I might have to if I can't find an answer) but the point is to keep the original email exactly the same, so should be sending it on as 8bit.

I have tried escaping the invalid octets in code, so for example replace byte 226 in the string with \xe2 (i think this just results in the same thing), and have tried replacing them with quoted-printable characters so 226 becomes '=E2' for example.

None of it works. I have seen 8bit emails with valid DKIM signatures in the wild, I just can't figure out how it's done. The documentation for this is all a bit vague and I'm considering writing a full tutorial with code examples once I figure this out.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so nobody knows. I gave up with this and cheated instead, by changing the type headers for the text and email bodies from 8-bit to quoted printable, retrieving the plaintext/html, encoding them to quoted printable, writing them back to the stream, then creating the dkim based on that. Not ideal as didn't want to change the email in anyway.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue if you use [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) to DKIM sign your messages.